# Overflow x not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal scrollable div containing images but not sure why the below code is not working .

Moreover the images in the div are getting displaying vertically instead of horizonatlly.
Can anyone ple help me understanding the problem here

```
 <div>
     <img  src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/143/321464099_a7cfcb95cf_t.jpg" />
     <img   src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3089/2796719087_c3ee89a730_t.jpg" />
     <img   src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/79/244441862_08ec9b6b49_t.jpg" />
 </div>
```

Below is the css :

```
div {
    width:400px;
    height:550px;
    border:thin solid black;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    position:relative;
}


img {
    width:350px;
    height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

because the display of `<img>` is `display: inline;`, you should prevent them breaking the line:

using:

```
div {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

to do this

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fish_ball/vrD6E/

Comment: set it as inline-block, float: left... above works fine as well upvoted +1

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    border: thin solid #FF0000;
    height: 550px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
     width: 400px;
  }
 img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    position: relative;
    right: -358px;
    top: -504px;
}
img:last-child {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    left: 724px;
   position: relative;
   top: -1000px;
 }
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/99xr7/

Comment: I think this approach is not neat enough, what do you think if there are 2 or more images there?

Comment: yes this example is anotherway. i konw         white-space:nowrap;  (or) white-space: nowrap, but this example is anotherway. you know